# Watch a variable from another thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I have a C# library, inside which there is a timer that keeps checking a boolean variable `ProcessFinished`. `ProcessFinished` is initialized as false.

**What I want** is that the main application needs to watch the variable Status from the library, and a message box should display once this `ProcessFinished` becomes true.

**The problem** I had is the message box never display if I simple execute the main application, but it displays if I step in the main application.

Here is the timer_tick code in main application:

```
    public Window1()
    {
        _fl = new FijiLauncherControl();

        this._statusTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();  // read log 4 times per sec 
        this._statusTimer.Interval = 125;
        this._statusTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(_statusTimer_Tick);
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void _statusTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (_fl.ProcessFinished)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Process is finished");
                _statusTimer.Stop();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }      

    private void FijiLaucherButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {         
        _statusTimer.Start();           
        _fl.LaunchFiji();

    }
```

where the `_fl` is the object of the class from the other library.

Inside the library, the timer code is like this:

```
 public FijiLauncherControl()
        {
            _ijmFile = "";
            _fijiExeFile = "";
            _logFile = "";
            _outputDir = "";
            _isLogOn = false;
            _processOn = false;
            _processFinished = false;
            _headless = true;
            _doneStr = "Procedure is finished.";

            _logFileCheckTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(500);  // read log 4 times per sec 
            _logFileCheckTimer.Enabled = true;
            _logFileCheckTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(_logFileCheckTimer_Elapsed);
        }

        void _logFileCheckTimer_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_processOn && IsLogOn)
            {
                try
                {
                    _processFinished = CheckStatuts();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

I am wondering what is going on here? Is there anyway I can see the message box shows up without stepping in? What is the right way to watch `ProcessFinished` from the main application?

Comment: Your approach is fundamentally wrong.  Start over again.  Research thread synchronization and wait handles.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey Is there an example that you know?

Comment: Simple code-review (1) Let InitilizeComponent() be the first call in your Window constructor. (2) Hook up events before enabling the Timer

Comment: @Frode. Did the change you mentioned, but still not seeing the message box.

Comment: I have a feeling that the two different threads (UI and the Timer.Timer thread) has _processFinished value out of sync. Try adding the volatile keyword as suggested in my answer further down. See: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/389730/The-unsung-hero-Volatile-keyword-Csharp-threading

Comment: Who sets the IsLogOn and _processOn property?

Comment: @Frode the UI, and it is always true

Comment: They are set to false in the FijiLauncherControl constructor

Comment: @Frode Yes they are set to be true from UI.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45955/discussion-between-nick-x-tsui-and-frode)

Comment: mark all bool fields in FijiLauncherControl with volatile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it not be better to fire an event from the thread and catch it. Then show the message box?

Like this maybe?

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
        {
            var logChecker = new LogChecker();
            logChecker.FinishedExvent += () => MessageBox.Show( "Finished" );
            logChecker.Start();
        }
    }

    internal class LogChecker
    {
        public void Start()
        {
            var thread = new Thread( CheckLog );
            thread.Start();
        }

        private void CheckLog()
        {
            var progress = 0;
            while ( progress < 3000 )
            {
                Thread.Sleep( 250 );
                progress += 250;
            }
            FinishedExvent();
        }

        public event TestEventHandler FinishedExvent;
    }

    internal delegate void TestEventHandler();
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more, better with some sample code please? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
   volatile bool _processFinished;
```